# Windows WinHTTP (C++ API) WinHttpSetCredentials with non-ascii (actually non-Windows-1252) error 87

Tags: c++, windows, http, character-encoding, winhttp

I am trying to use the WinHTTP library with Basic Authentication.
I'm testing the case where the user name or password has "special" characters (ie, not in Windows-1252) and I cannot seem to set the credentials using 
WinHttpSetCredentials

The outcome is an error, with code 87 ("The parameter is incorrect")

'extended ascii' (128~255) in the sense of Windows-1252 will work.

I've sniffed the headers, and it seems like WinHTTP re-encodes my user/pass in Windows-1252.

My call looks like this, and it returns false when user or pass have non-Win1252 characters.

```
::WinHttpSetCredentials(requestHdl, dwTarget, m_authScheme /*basic*/,
     user.c_str() /*wstring in UCS2*/,
     pass.c_str(), /*wstring in UCS2*/ 
     NULL /*reserved?*/)
```

Any suggestions as to why this call doesn't support general wstring characters properly? I can't find anything in the documentation (except for a strange flag about assuming the data is ASCII...).

Comment: If you compile the code with a C++ compilert it **is not C**, but C++. Identical syntax/grammar does not imply identical semantics! They are different languages, C++ is not a superset of C.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite Ok, thanks. I get that. I was confused on what to call it, since the crux of the question is platform specific anyway. That's to say that the semantics of C vs C++ are not important to this question, so using one or the other doesn't really communicate better or worse, I'd say.